# Webpack can't find (font) dependencies

Tags: laravel, npm, webpack, yarnpkg, laravel-mix

NPM/Webpack can't find dependencies with Laravel Mix

```
These dependencies were not found:

* font-awesome
* ionicons


ERROR in multi lodash jquery bootstrap-sass fastclick jquery-slimscroll admin-lte icheck ionicons font-awesome datatables.net datatables.net-bs
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'font-awesome' in 'D:\Laragon'
 @ multi lodash jquery bootstrap-sass fastclick jquery-slimscroll admin-lte icheck ionicons font-awesome datatables.net datatables.net-bs
```

More clearly. These are installed (can find them in node_modules) and require location is correct. I'm also using more packages, and these problems are related to, coincidentally, the only fonts in my webpack.

They are available in the `package.json` and `package.json.lock`.

Installed trying different methods: firstly `npm install` and `--save-dev`, also tried `yarn install` and `yarn add`.

My `webpack.mix.js`:

```
let mix = require('laravel-mix');

/*
 |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
 | Mix Asset Management
 |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
 |
 | Mix provides a clean, fluent API for defining some Webpack build steps
 | for your Laravel application. By default, we are compiling the Sass
 | file for the application as well as bundling up all the JS files.
 |
 */

mix.webpackConfig({
    module: {
        loaders: [
            {
                test: /\.js?/,
                exclude: [/node_modules/, /styles/],
                loaders: ['babel'],
                include: path.join(__dirname, 'src')
            },
            {
                test: /\.scss$/,
                loader: 'style!css!resolve-url!sass?sourceMap'
            },
            {
                test: /\.css$/,
                loader: "style-loader!css-loader"
            },
            {
                test: /\.woff(2)?(\?v=[0-9]\.[0-9]\.[0-9])?$/,
                loader: 'url-loader?limit=10000&mimetype=application/font-woff'
            },
            {
                test: /\.(ttf|eot|svg)(\?v=[0-9]\.[0-9]\.[0-9])?$/,
                loader: 'file-loader'
            }
        ]
    }
});

mix.js('resources/assets/js/app.js', 'public/js')
   .sass('resources/assets/sass/app.scss', 'public/css');

mix.js('resources/assets/js/auth.js', 'public/js')
   .sass('resources/assets/sass/auth.scss', 'public/css');

mix.js('resources/assets/js/admin-lte.js', 'public/js')
   .sass('resources/assets/sass/admin-lte.scss', 'public/css');

mix.autoload({
    jquery: [ '$', 'jQuery', 'jquery'],
    DataTable: 'datatables.net-bs'
});

mix.extract([
    'lodash', 'jquery', 'bootstrap-sass',
    'fastclick', 'jquery-slimscroll', 'admin-lte',
    'icheck', 'ionicons', 'font-awesome',
    'datatables.net', 'datatables.net-bs'
], 'public/js/vendor.js');

mix.version();
```

I also tried it without the `mix.webpackConfig`, adding the config this was a desperate attempt to fix the fonts.

Here is my package.json:

```
{
    "private": true,
    "scripts": {
        "dev": "npm run development",
        "development": "cross-env NODE_ENV=development node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js --progress --hide-modules --config=node_modules/laravel-mix/setup/webpack.config.js",
        "watch": "cross-env NODE_ENV=development node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js --watch --progress --hide-modules --config=node_modules/laravel-mix/setup/webpack.config.js",
        "watch-poll": "npm run watch -- --watch-poll",
        "hot": "cross-env NODE_ENV=development node_modules/webpack-dev-server/bin/webpack-dev-server.js --inline --hot --config=node_modules/laravel-mix/setup/webpack.config.js",
        "prod": "npm run production",
        "production": "cross-env NODE_ENV=production node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js --no-progress --hide-modules --config=node_modules/laravel-mix/setup/webpack.config.js"
    },
    "devDependencies": {
        "admin-lte": "^2.4.2",
        "axios": "^0.17",
        "bootstrap": "^4.0.0",
        "cross-env": "^5.1.3",
        "datatables.net": "^1.10.16",
        "fastclick": "^1.0.6",
        "font-awesome": "^4.7.0",
        "icheck": "^1.0.2",
        "ionicons": "^3.0.0",
        "jquery": "^3.3.1",
        "jquery-slimscroll": "^1.3.8",
        "laravel-mix": "^2.0",
        "lodash": "^4.17.4",
        "popper.js": "^1.12",
        "script-loader": "^0.7.2"
    },
    "dependencies": {
        "bootstrap-sass": "^3.3.7",
        "datatables.net-bs": "^1.10.16"
    }
}
```

And in my .scss:

```
@import '~font-awesome/scss/font-awesome';
```

Both on Mac and Windows 10

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Getting rid of `font-awesome` and `ionicons` from the extract function solves the problem.

Comment: can you elaborate your answer please.

Answer (score 0):

Include Font Awesome into your NPM config

```
"devDependencies": {
   ......
   ......
    "font-awesome": "^4.7.0"
}
```

Run `npm update`

And then your app.scss include this

```
// Font Awesome
@import "~font-awesome/scss/font-awesome.scss";
```

Run `npm dev` or `npm watch

Comment: I've done all of that, already did. Will include them in my main question. Doesn't work though.